# How to make sure a S3 presigned GetObject URL can only be accessed from an authorized device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I want to provide a presigned s3 url for authenticated users to download files. I have a JWT based authentication on my backend and the URL can be generated on my backend based on the token. So if a user is authenticated on a device, they can click on a button and it opens a new tab pointing at the presigned url. My question is, how to prevent the user to copy the url on to an unauthenticated device and access the file from there? I referred to [AWS S3 authenticated user access using presigned URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404672/aws-s3-authenticated-user-access-using-presigned-urls) this, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407211/1207049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no, that is not possible, a pre-signed URL is valid from any browser and any device. You cannot prevent a user from copying and sharing the link.

The only thing you could do is reduce the duration for which the presigned url is valid, if you open the link in a new tab and set the duration of the presigned url only be e.g. 5 seconds you massively *reduce the chance* or the effect of the user being able to share the link in time.